# Mongodb - find referred document and retrieve it with only one element in its inner array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have this data in mongodb:

Process document:

```
process: {
    procnumber: '1',
    person: {
        $ref: 'person',
        $id: ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772")
    }
}
process: {
    procnumber: '2',
    person: {
        $ref: 'person',
        $id: ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab996")
    }
}
```

Person document:

```
person: {
    _id: ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),
    name:'person_1',
    obsarray:[{date:ISODate("2017-02-13"),obs:'1.this is one'},{date:ISODate("2017-02-20"),obs:'1.this is two'},{date:ISODate("2017-02-01"),obs:'1.this is three'}]
}
person: {
    _id: ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab996"),
    name:'person_2',
    obsarray:[{date:ISODate("2017-02-17"),obs:'2.this is one'},{date:ISODate("2017-02-27"),obs:'2.this is two'},{date:ISODate("2017-02-28"),obs:'2.this is three'}]
}
```

And I want to query it so that the query returns fields from both Process and Person, and at the same time, have the "obsarray" only return the document with the most recent date.

Example of a desired output:

```
{
procnum:'1',
person: {
    name:'person_1',
    obsarray: {
        date:ISODate("2017-02-20"),
        obs:'1.this is two'
    }
}
```

I've tried using aggregation, however I have failed to deal with the reference:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {$match:{name:{$exists:true}}},
    {$unwind:'$obsarray' },
    {$sort:{'obsarray.date':-1}},
    {$group:{
        _id:'$_id',
        obsarray:{$first: '$obsarray.date'},
        name:{$first:'$name'}}
    }
])
```

Is there any way of populating the 'Person' ref from 'Process' and then apply the aggregate so as to have the output with fields from both documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to change `DBRef` to manual reference. Something like

```
var ProcessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    procnumber: String,
    person: {
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,        
     ref: 'Person'
    }
});
```

After updating your document should look like below.

```
process: {
    procnumber: '1',
    person: {
        _id: ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772")
    }
}
```

You can now use `$lookup` to get the information from other collection in aggregation query.

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {$match:{name:{$exists:true}}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "process",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "person._id",
        as: "person_process"}
    },
    {$unwind:'$person_process'},
    {$unwind:'$obsarray' },
    {$sort:{'obsarray.date':-1}},
    {$group:{
        _id:'$_id',
        obsarray:{$first: '$obsarray.date'},
        name:{$first:'$name'}},
        procnum:{$first:'$person_process.procnum'}}
    }
])
```